# Push a node-red flow to a docker container

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, node-red

I've began using pretty recently both node-red and docker separately, so hope this question doesn't offend anyone.

Going straight to the point: I would like to use a docker container of a node-red flow as an IoT azure edge module to link both the IoT hub I've been using with a pre-existing docker image and the node-red flow I've built for a specific project, but I'm unsure this is possible.

I've found documentation about using node-red running under docker and installing custom plug-ins, but them all miss the image part itself (how to push it to my docker hub). My question then is how to push an existing node-red flow to a Docker hub to be used on its own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you edit the Dockerfile to add your own `package.json` to add the extra nodes you can also add a `flow.json` file to `/data` and Node-RED will load this flow when the container is started.

Otherwise you can just connect to the web editor as normal to edit the existing flow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @hardillb! You mean opening a shell in the container and replacing `package.json` by my previous `flow.json`? How is that done in the command shell?

Comment: No, I mean either mounting flow.json as a volume or rebuilding the Docker container from the `Dockerfile` and adding the file to the image

Comment: The second part of your reply is another issue I'm facing; when running nodeRed through docker I'm unable to connect to the web editor normally as when running it through my cmd. I guess it has to do with the IP I'm browsing, but none have worked (127.0.0.1:1800 nor my local/public IP). Any ideas why?

Comment: You said you had deployed the docker container in Azure, so why would you try and connect to your local machine?